# Openattic installation for ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ceph

Can anybody share any reference regarding how to install openattic 3.7 in ubuntu 16.04 if ceph cluster is deployed with ceph-deploy?

Answer (score 1):

There is no official support for Openattic 3.7 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Only openATTIC version: 2.02.21 - Barely works, needs Django version between 1.6 to 1.7 only.

Turns out theres no full support for 16.04 LTS.
https://tracker.openattic.org/browse/OP-1484

Follow the openATTIC documentation - https://openattic.readthedocs.io/en/2.x/install_guides/oA_installation.html#installation-on-ubuntu-linux

If you want to install older version as mentioned above on your Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://apt.openattic.org/ $(lsb_release -cs) main"
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openattic -y
```